# How to pivot for a 2-column table where index contains duplicate values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, pivot

This is the current dataframe:

```
    PersonID    TestResult
12    1.423000e+03    68270
13    1.423000e+03    68270
17    1.978000e+03    9
18    1.978000e+03    746
24    2.384000e+03    166197
25    2.384000e+03    166197
```

And this is the kind of result I am looking for;

```
    PersonID    TestResult
12    1.423000e+03    68270    68270
17    1.978000e+03    9    746
```

Comment: Should the output be a single column, containing a list of the values?

Comment: Convert index to column and then use `pivot_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC and you wish to have the values aggregated as a list, because you seem to be interested in keeping both values for each index, then you need to use `list` as the `aggfunc` for the `pivot_table` function:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index='PersonID',values='TestResult',aggfunc=list)
```

Outputs:

```
                TestResult
PersonID                  
1           [68270, 68270]
2                 [9, 746]
3         [166197, 166197]
```

Comment: Great! This worked perfectly for me

Comment: My pleasure! Let me know if you need anything else!